# Focus Lost animation on Android/Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: java, android

On my tablet, whenever you put your finger down on something clickable (like a menu item), it highlights as a pale blue. When you drag your finger off, there's a nice little fade.

Does anyone know where this animation/colour lives in the SDK? I want to programmatically play this animation on a `Button` that I have.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `android:exitFadeDuration` attribute in your button's background StateListDrawable:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="100">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```

Please notice that this just works for Android >= 3.0 (API Level 11)

Docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#exitFadeDuration